# How to import Julia packages into Python

Tags: python, julia

One can use Julia's built-in modules and functions using the `juliacall` package. for example:

```py
>>> from juliacall import Main as jl
>>> import numpy as np

# Create a 2*2 random matrix
>>> arr = jl.rand(2,2)

>>> arr
<jl [0.28133223988783074 0.22498491616860727; 0.008312971104033062 0.12927167014532326]>

# Check whether Numpy can recognize the shape of the array or not
>>> np.array(arr).shape
(2, 2)

>>> type(np.array(arr))
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

Then I'm curious to know if importing an installed julia package into Python is possible? For example, let's say that one wants to import [`Flux.jl`](https://github.com/FluxML/Flux.jl) into Python. Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found it by scrutinizing the pictures of the [second example](https://github.com/cjdoris/PythonCall.jl#example-2-calling-julia-from-python) of the `juliacall` GitHub page. According to the example, I'm able to **import** `Flux.jl` by taking these steps:

```py
>>> from juliacall import Main as jl
>>> jl.seval("using Flux")
```

Also, one can **install** any registered Julia package using `Pkg` in Python:

```py
>>> from juliacall import Main as jl
>>> jl.Pkg.add("Flux")

# After a successful installation

>>> jl.Pkg.status()
Status `C:\Users\Shayan\miniconda3\envs\im\julia_env\Project.toml`
  [587475ba] Flux v0.14.10
  [6099a3de] PythonCall v0.9.15

# This indicates that the installation was successful
```

### Additional note

One can use Julia packages in Python using the [`pyjulia`](https://pypi.org/project/julia/) package that can be installed using `pip install julia` in Python. Afterward, the following commands should be entered:

```py
>>> import julia
>>> julia.install()

# Then

>>> from julia import Pkg
>>> Pkg.add("Flux")

# After a successful installation
>>> Pkg.status()
Status `C:\Users\Shayan\.julia\environments\v1.10\Project.toml`
  [587475ba] Flux v0.14.10

# This indicates that the installation was successful

>>> from julia import Flux
```

You can also say, `from julia import Flux as flx`. **Note that using `juliacall` is recommended.**