# How to load a custom Julia package in Python using Python's juliacall

Tags: python, julia

I already know [How to import Julia packages into Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73070845/how-to-import-julia-packages-into-python).

However, now I have created my own simple Julia package with the following command:
`using Pkg;Pkg.generate("MyPack");Pkg.activate("MyPack");Pkg.add("StatsBase")`
where the file `MyPack/src/MyPack.jl` has the following contents:

```
module MyPack
using StatsBase

function f1(x, y)
   return 3x + y
end
g(x) = StatsBase.std(x)

export f1

end
```

Now I would like to load this Julia package in Python via `juliacall` and call `f1` and `g` functions.
I have already run `pip3 install juliacall` from command line. How do I call the above functions from Python?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to run the following code to load the `MyPack` package from Python via `juliacall`

```
from juliacall import Main as jl
from juliacall import Pkg as jlPkg

jlPkg.activate("MyPack")  # relative path to the folder where `MyPack/Project.toml` should be used here 

jl.seval("using MyPack")
```

Now you can use the function (note that calls to non exported functions require package name):

```
>>> jl.f1(4,7)
19

>>> jl.f1([4,5,6],[7,8,9]).to_numpy()
array([19, 23, 27], dtype=object)

>>> jl.MyPack.g(numpy.arange(0,3))
1.0
```

Note another option for calling Julia from Python that seems to be more difficult to configure as of today is the `pip install julia` package which is described here: [I have a high-performant function written in Julia, how can I use it from Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64241264/i-have-a-high-performant-function-written-in-julia-how-can-i-use-it-from-python)