# Convert Julia type to a Python/NumPy dtype

Tags: python, numpy, type-conversion, julia

I would like to convert a Julia type to a Python type / NumPy dtype:

```
from juliacall import Main as jl
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1,2,3], dtype=jl.Float64)
# fails with:
# TypeError: Cannot interpret 'Julia: Float64' as a data type
```

The docs mention:

> From Julia, one converts Julia objects to Python explicitly using Py(x)

but `jl.Py(jl.Float64)` is still `juliacall.TypeValue`. Is such conversion possible?

Thank you for any guidance!

Comment: When using jl.Py(jl.Float64), you are converting the type jl.Float64 (not a number of that type). As per the same docs page you are citing, converting a Julia Type via Py() leads to the Python type juliacall.TypeValue. You have to use Py() on the actual numbers.

Note that even a juliacall.TypeValue object is indeed a Python object and can be used as such.

Comment: there's a distinction between a python type, and a numpy dtype.  A python float can stored in an array as `np.float64`.  Otherwise it will `object` dtype, a reference as in a list.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you are not *converting* a Julia type to Python type but rather *creating* a NumPy array of values of the type `jl.Float64`. Since this is not one of the types NumPy understands it cannot accept it and hence raises the error.

For the NumPy you should probably create an array of type `np.float64` (the default on 64b systems) to obtain the equivalent of Julia's array.

This array can be then used to call a `my_matrix_function` from Julia while converting the array explicitly in the following way:

```
jl.my_matrix_function(jl.convert(jl.Array[jl.Float64, 3], a))
```

Of course you need your my_matrix_function` available to call - [importing Julia packages in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73070845/how-to-import-julia-packages-into-python) may be of use here.

You can do the conversion simpler by wrapping the conversion and making another function on Julia's side:

```
jl.seval("wrap_my_matrix_function(x) = my_matrix_function(convert(Matrix, x))")
```

This one you can use this way:

```
jl.wrap_my_matrix_function(a)
```

directly on your NumPy array `a`.

You can also start directly with a Julia array:

```
julia_a = jl.Array([1,2,3])
python_a = np.array(julia_a)  # should you need to use it in NumPy
jl.matrix_function(julia_a)
```

You can check a [few examples here](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/passing-numpy-arrays-between-python-and-julia/25826/2) or [the documentation on the array passing here](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/convert-numpy-arrays-to-julia-arrays-by-default-pythoncall-juliacall/90671).